# Is there a way to sync iCloud data with a Nokia phone?

Tags: icloud

I am using iCloud but I also have a Nokia phone that I use for emergencies. Apparently it has a calendar and an address book built-in.

Is there a way, using some software to sync the Nokia phone with iCloud via PC or mac?

Comment: The only way I manage this is 1) Sync iCloud with my Mac 2) Use iSync from OSX 10.6 to sync my Mac with my Nokia

Comment: So I need iSync to use the Nokia desktop software (on a Mac)?

Comment: I don't use Nokia desktop software. Instead I use an [iSync plugin](http://europe.nokia.com/support/product-support/isync/compatibility-and-download) developed by Nokia for my specific phone model. In case you have not saved a backup of iSync from Snow Lepard, you can download it [here](http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/9355/apple-isync).

Comment: As you will understand, this does sync with iCloud, but not independently from you Mac.

Comment: Of course. I only need my Nokia phone to be somewhat up-to-date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way to sync a non-Apple device with iCloud is to sync your Mac with iCloud, then sync you may with the device using iSync.

Comment: MobileMe was leagues better...

Comment: MobileMe was designed for different purposes. It was also plagued with many problems. When iCloud gets replaced in another 5-10 years, we'll be wishing we had iCloud back.

Comment: Yeah. One of the "different purposes" was interoperability. Now Apple switched to "contain customers" mode.